# Characters displaying in wrong language

Tags: c, bgi

I'm working on a project for university using `c`.

We were given the framework for the project (basic GUI implementation using BGI).

For some reason it is all the text in the display windows is coming out in south east Asian characters.

[image]

Here is the code I'm currently using for this (well what seems relevant at least),

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void startScreen() {
   settextstyle(EUROPEAN_FONT, 0, 16);
   outtextxy((getmaxx() / 2) - (textwidth("TOWER OF POWER") / 2), 0, "TOWER OF POWER");
   outtextxy((getmaxx() / 2) - (textwidth("PRESS ANY KEY")/2), getmaxy() - textheight("PRESS ANY KEY"), "PRESS ANY KEY");

   tower();

   readkey();
   clearviewport();
}

void main(void) {
    // Initialise graphic window (x = 639 , y = 479)
    int gd = DETECT, gm = 0;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "");
    startScreen();
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Yikes  Why do I keep read about universities using 20+ year old C compilers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you clarify: a) which is the compiler and its version?, b) `BGI` is Borland Graphic Interface - is it right? c) which OS and version? @DavidHoelzer I can't believe too - I used BGI as student and it was .. 26 years ago! Wow!

Comment: the header file: `conio.h` is strickly for a windows OS.  I.E. it is not portable.  Suggest using the standard C library functions for i/O with the user and not using `conio.h`

Comment: here is why your getting unexpected font:  `settextstyle(EUROPEAN_FONT, 0, 16);`

Comment: the posted code is including `stdlib.h` twice, Why?

Comment: it is poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  Suggest removing the statement: `#include <math.h>`

Comment: regarding: `void main(void) {`  In modern C, there are only two valid signatures for `main()` Both of them have a returned  type of `int`, not `void`

Comment: @AlexYu A) Visual Studio 2017 15.9.5 (but others using a 2015 version have the same problem)
B) Yes, I'm not even going to get into how frustrating this class is (seriously I had a programming class last semester and 2 this semester and they are still going over the basics (how to do maths))
C) windows 10 pro 1809

Comment: @user3629249 replies in order of comments

1) It doesn't need to be portable, and if i remember correctly I was some of it's functionality.

2) I hadn't noticed stblib.h, thanks I'll fix that, but the main problem existed before I added the second.

3) As I said I only included the relevant code, math.h is being used in the code.

4) That part of the program was given to me by the lecturer.

Comment: @user3629249 sorry didn't see
`settextstyle(EUROPEAN_FONT, 0, 16); `
not sure what you mean, I have tried using different fonts and I'm still getting the non-latin characters

Comment: @AlexYu I believe that I have worked out a possible reason for the problem, I think it's using the hex ascii values and trying to put them into unicode. i found this by checking the hex ascii for two letters combining them and putting the result into a unicode checker. it's not the exact character but it seems that doing it that way puts all the characters in the CJK sections of unicode.